# Does Google Oauth client have no.of user restriction on verified app?

Tags: google-drive-api

Do google Oauth client have number of user's restriction if the app is verified from Google?

Comment: From [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2): *"Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to obtain new access tokens."*  They apparently don't distinguish between verified apps and unverified ones.

Comment: So can any user generate access token from the refresh token any number of times? And does the client have limitation that only these much user can get access token and only these much user can use same client?

Comment: That's a good question.  What does the documentation say about that?

Comment: I have read somewhere it's depend on Clint and user combination. And I am not sure is restricted to only the non verified Oauth client? Or for both?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh tokens never expire. However, there are some limitations:

> You must write your code to anticipate the possibility that a granted refresh token might no longer work. A refresh token might stop working for one of these reasons:
>
> - The user has revoked your app's access.
> - The refresh token has not been used for six months.
> - The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail scopes.
> - The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live) refresh tokens.
>
> There is currently a limit of 50 refresh tokens per user account per client. If the limit is reached, creating a new refresh token automatically invalidates the oldest refresh token without warning. This limit does not apply to service accounts.
>
> There is also a larger limit on the total number of refresh tokens a user account or service account can have across all clients. Most normal users won't exceed this limit but a developer's test account might.
>
> If you need to authorize multiple programs, machines, or devices, one workaround is to limit the number of clients that you authorize per user account to 15 or 20. If you are a G Suite admin, you can create additional admin users and use them to authorize some of the clients.

#### Reference

- [Google OAuth2 expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration)